# PHP-FPM is not working with htaccess

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7

I have a `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example.com"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
<Directory "/var/www/html/example.com">
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteOptions InheritBefore        
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule ^([^\.]+\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example.com/$1 [L,P]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And an `.htaccess` file located at `/var/www/html/example.com/mysub/.htaccess`. Inside of the `.htaccess` file, I have:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysub

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|css|js|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

**The issue:** I can navigate to `example.com` in my browser just fine. However, if I try to go to `example.com/mysub`, it shows me `example.com/index.php` instead of `example.com/mysub/index.php`.

I assume this means `$1` in the VirtualHost RewriteRule does not contain the `mysub` directory prefix? Why is that? I thought maybe the RewriteBase (being different) in both files was the issue, but modifying it did not change the output.

I believe the issue is in the VirtualHost mod_rewrite. On a different server (Centos 5), the website works perfectly (although I'm not using php-fpm). I would prefer not to modify the htaccess as it's part of 3rd party code.

PHP 5.4; CentOS 7; Apache 2.4

**EDIT:** It works when I move the htaccess Rewrites to the VirtualHost file and modify the paths to work with a base of /. This isn't ideal though since the 3rd party code can be updated at any time with a modified htaccess.

Comment: How is Apache connected to PHP-FPM socket? A proxy to `fastcgi://...` URL, or maybe using *mod_fastcgi* and `FastCgiExternalServer ...`? If the latter, have you tried `RewriteBase /???/mysub`, where *???* is the 1st argument to *FastCgiExternalServer*?

Comment: you'll need LogLevel rewrite:trace8 to debug this one.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz Bottom line of VirtualHost: proxy to `fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000`. I'll duplicate the conditions in a test environment and post back (LogLevel is already pretty high).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the Rewrite outside of the Directory directive of the VirtualHost solved the problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example.com"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
<Directory "/var/www/html/example.com">
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritBefore

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [L,P]
</VirtualHost>
```